# How can I replace a variable in a get query in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, url

I have an URL

```
http://example.com/test?xyz=27373&page=4&test=5
```

which I want to tranform by replacing the `page=4` through `page=XYZ`

how can I do that with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use

```
$oldurl = "http://test.com/test?xyz=27373&page=4&test=5"
$newurl = preg_replace("/page=\d+/", "page=XYZ", $oldurl);
```

Or you can reconstruct the URL from `$_GET` superglobal.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to set the value of xyz to the page value? I think you might need to specify a bit more. But this is easy to modify if you dont know regex.

```
$url = 'http://test.com/test?xyz=27373&page=4&test=5';
$urlQuery = parseUrl($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($urlQuery, $queryData);
$queryData['page'] = $queryData['xyz'];
unset($queryData['xyz']);
$query = http_build_query($queryData);
$outUrl = substr_replace($url, $query, strpos($url, '?'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://test.com/test?xyz=27373&page=4&test=5';
preg_match('/xyz=([^&]+)/', $url, $newpage);
$new = preg_replace('/page=([^&]+)/', $newpage[0], $url);
$new = preg_replace('/xyz=([^&]+)&/', '', $new);
```

This will turn

http://test.com/test?xyz=27373&page=4&test=5

into

http://test.com/test?page=27373&test=5

Forgive me if this isn't what you were looking to do, but your question isn't quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could do something with a regular expression.   However, if the URL you've given is the one you're currently handling, you already have all the request variables in $_Request.

So, rebuild the URL, replacing the values you want to replace, and then redirect to the new URL.

Otherwise, go find a regexp tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your own page (and you are currently on that page) those variables will appear in a global variable named `$_GET`, and you could use something like `array_slice`, `unset` or `array_filter` to remove the unwanted variables and regenerate the URL.

If you just have that URL as a string, then what exactly are the criteria for removing the information? Technically there's no difference between

```
...?xyz=27373&page=4&test=5
```

and

```
...?test=5&xyz=27373&page=4
```

so just removing all but the first parameter might not be what you want.

If you want to remove everything except the `xyz` param. Take a look at `parse_url` and `parse_str`

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you trying to do? The question is a little unclear.

$XYZ = $_GET['xyz'];
$PAGE = $_GET['page'];

?

Answer (score -1):

Are wanting to replace each value with another, or replace both with one?